# Adding gwt Tag inside GSP Page

Tags: gwt, grails, gsp

Is it possible to include gwt tags into gsp page. I've installed gwt grails plugin but I haven't been able to achieve this yet.

Its possible to include dojo tags into gsp page after u install the dojo grails plugin

Comment: What tags are you talking about? GWT only has a single script tag to load the javascript, and that's not a "gwt tag" but simply an html tag for loading an external js file.

Comment: I meant things like <g:Label> where g stands for gwt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mixing up the context where these tags are supposed to be used.

GSP tags are for creating a server-side template that will be rendered and sent to the browser as completed HTML. GWT's `ui:binder` tags are for creating a template that's compiled by GWT and used to generate a page on the client-side within the browser. They operate in two different realms.